# Having trouble understanding classes and properties

Tags: c#, .net, class

Although I know  this is an easy issue and a gap in my knowledge - please keep in mind I'm writing this code to learn (and detailed explanations or best practice suggestions would greatly help in this).

Firstly, here's my class:

```
namespace CCQ.Crawler._2010
{
    public class MSSQL
    {
        public MSSQL(string connectionString)
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public static string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Class to house statements that insert or update data into the database
        /// </summary>
        public class Upserts
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Add or update a new entry on the site collection table
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="siteCollectionName"></param>
            public void SiteCollection(string siteCollectionName)
            {
                const string queryString =
                @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[SiteCollections]
                                   ([SnapShotDate]
                                   ,[SiteCollectionName]
                                   ,[SiteWebCount]
                                   ,[ContentDatabase]
                                   ,[SiteWebApplication])
                                 VALUES
                                  (@snapShotDate, @siteCollectionName, @siteWebCount, @contentDatabase, @siteWebApplication)";
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("snapShotDate", DateTime.Today.Date);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("siteCollectionName", siteCollectionName);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my main program file:

```
namespace CCQ.Crawler._2010
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static string _connectionString;
        private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public static string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString))
                {
                    _connectionString = AES.DecryptFromBase64String(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatastoreConnection"]);
                }
                return _connectionString;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string version = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program)).GetName().Version.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] SharePoint Crawler started with version '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), version);
            Logger.Info(string.Format("[{0}] SharePoint Crawler started with version '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), version));

            try
            {
                var query = new MSSQL(ConnectionString);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(String.Format("[{0}] {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), ex.GetBaseException()));
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), ex.GetBaseException());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I thought I could do with this class, was this:

```
var query = new MSSQL(ConnectionString).Upserts;

query.SiteCollection("testing");
```

But, well, that doesn't work. The error I'm getting when I try to declare the class is:

> Class name is not valid at this point

I know there's a huge gap somewhere in my knowledge / class construction which is why, but I don't quite know where to begin - where's the error in my thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
var query = new MSSQL(ConnectionString).Upserts;
```

you are actually constructing a new instance of the MSSQL class then using the syntax as if `Upserts` was a property on it that you are trying to access.

Instead, to instantiate your nested class, you should do something like this:

```
var mssql = new MSSQL("your connection string");
var query = new MSSQL.Upserts();
```

**BUT...**

The way you are storing the conection string in a static property of the enclosing class is a bit strange, and initializing the static propery in a non-static constructor is strange too.

You probably don't need to have `Upserts` be a nested class. Try making it a method instead.

Also, your connection string can be stored in an instance field/property rather than being static.

Comment: What about my connection string?

Comment: The way you have written it, you need to construct an instance of the `MSSQL` first to initialize the static `ConnectionString` property, but that is not the best way to do things. See my edit for more info.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks, looking into it more - appreciate the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

'query' is of type MSSQL.  The SiteCollection property belongs to the Upserts type.  Although you have defined the Upserts type within MSSQL as a nested type, you aren't actually using the Upserts type in your MSSQL object (for example, as a property).

The quickest way I can see to get this up and running is to add an Upserts property to your MSSQL class and instantiate it in your constructor.

```
public Upserts Upserts { get; private set; }
```

You will then be able to access the method by the following means:

```
query.Upserts.SiteCollection("...");
```

Alternatively, you could just modify Upserts to receive a connection string and instantiate it directly... this is a step toward removing MSSQL from the equation though.

I realise you're writing this to wrap your head around classes and properties, so I wont comment on whether this is or isn't a good approach to DAL.

Comment: You can find a lot of guidance on this topic on the web. Although a little dated, this article will give you a start: [Creating a Data Access Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx).  Keep in mind that for the most part these days, devs will opt for using an ORM such as NHibernate or EntityFramework rather than roll their own DAL from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to use nested class in this case. You could Try this:

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>MSSQL class</para>
/// </summary>
public class MSSQL
{
    #region Class field declaration

    private string f_connectionString;

    #endregion

    #region Public method

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Static method for getting the class instance.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p_connectionString">MSSQL connection string</param>
    /// <returns><see cref="MSSQL"/></returns>
    public static MSSQL Create(string p_connectionString)
    {
        return new MSSQL(p_connectionString);
    }

    public void SiteCollection(string p_siteCollectionName)
    {
        //Your Logic here.
    }

    #endregion


    #region Constructor
    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Hide the default constructor</para>
    /// </summary>
    private MSSQL()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Private constructor for Static method</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p_connectionString">MSSQL connection string</param>
    private MSSQL(string p_connectionString)
    {
        this.f_connectionString = p_connectionString;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

By this code, you could create the instance of this class by:

```
var instance = MSSQL.Create("ConnectionString");
```

Get the SiteCollection by:

```
var siteCollection = instance.SiteCollection("Testing");
```